# TweetSharp - Stop waiting for acceptance to follow a private account

Tags: c#, tweetsharp

I research the method that will stop to wait for permission to follow an account when an account is private.

I'm not sure of being understood, so I explain my idea.

When I follow a private account with **twitterservice.FollowUser** method, the account  receive ask to accept to follow him by my own account. But after x days, if this account does not always allow or not the right to follow him (no action from this account), I whish I could withdraw me request.

I try to use **twitterservice.UnfollowUser** that return a successful operation, for monitoring against the request is not removed.

What method or process to do that ?

Comment: Hello there, I don't think twitter provide such an endpoint (on the public api). I think https://twittercommunity.com will be the best place to ask this question as the developers of the api can provide an answer to your question.